# Объединение таблиц с одинаковой структурой

Tags: база-данных

Добрый день!

Суть - получить общую таблицу без пустых полей (в теории) после получения данных с нескольких сайтов.

Вот допустим после парсинга 2 сайтов получаю 2 таблицы (50 строк в 1 и 80 во 2ой), надо объединить их без дубликатов в случае совпадения 1 или 2 параметров (сайт или название). В любую базу данных можно загрузить csv как я понял, так что не важно в какой программе делать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: Пока ничего. Я только сегодня столкнулся с этой проблемой

Comment: Здесь не принято выполнять работу за кого-то, а помогать с конкретными вопросами. Загрузите данные в БД, составте запрос, если возникнуть затруднения, задайте  вопрос с описанием конкретной проблемы.